# AngularJS $http.get not pulling back

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Why is this not pulling back anything?  I keep getting the error message and I cannot figure out why.  I tried to use JSONParse on the response data and reassigning it to the $scope but that didn't help.  I have no errors in my F12 Console.  I know JQuery is a much better solution but I prefer the Javascript, i'll take both though. Thanks ahead of time.

```
var controlSeletor = angular.module('moduleName', []);
controlSeletor .controller('variableController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("data.json")
  .then(
    function(response) {
    // Success
    $scope.variable = response.data;
   },
    function(response){
    // Error
    alert("Error!");
    }
);
});
```

The json is a separate file and looks like this:

```
[{
  "url": "place.html",
  "name": "Bob",
  "pic": "bob.jpg"

},
{
  "url": "place.html",
  "name": "Mike",
  "pic": "mike.jpg"

},
{
  "url": "place.html",
  "name": "Tony",
  "pic": "tony.jpg"
}];
```

Comment: debugging 101 tip: see where your code does this `function(response){
    // Error
    alert("Error!");
    }` ... why not `console.error(response);` - then you can see what the error is!!

Comment: `The json is a separate file and looks like this` - that's not actually [valid JSON](http://www.json.org/), because the key's are not enclosed in `"..."`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the console.error(response);

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not valid, change it as follows,

> [   {
>       "url": "place.html",
>       "name": "Bob",
>       "pic": "bob.jpg"   },   {
>       "url": "place.html",
>       "name": "Mike",
>       "pic": "mike.jpg"   },   {
>       "url": "place.html",
>       "name": "Tony",
>       "pic": "tony.jpg"   } ]

```
var app = angular.module('filterApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('data.json').
  then(function(response) {
    $scope.variable = response.data;
  });
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Dc0ViULpQ3Ri9DTLRFyy?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

**Few observations :**

- Controller declaration is not correct. It should be `controlSeletor.controller` instead of `controlSeletor .controller`.
- Your `JSON` is not a `valid JSON`.

[image]

Valid `JSON` should be like this :

[image]

Comment: The space I accidentally put in when I was posting the question.  Thanks for the JSON advice.  All good now

Comment: @JMizzle If this answer helps you mark it as a correct so that it will be helpful for others as well.